# How to neaten up this scala code?

Tags: scala

I've found myself wanting to do this a bit recently.

I can take a string, split it and then map over the individual elements, but how can I only perform an action if an array has a certain number of elements?

As an example I'm trying to parse an `Authorization` HTTP header which can have a value like `Basic MTAyNTpteXBhc3M=`. Here's what I've got, but it's verbose. How can I make it more succinct?

```
  def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = {

    val schemaValue = authHeader.split(' ')

    if (schemaValue.length == 2) {
     if (schemaValue(0).toLowerCase == "basic") {
       val decodedHeader = new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(schemaValue(1)))

       val decodedParts =  decodedHeader.split(':')

       if (decodedParts.length == 2) {
         Some(decodedParts(0), decodedParts(1))
       }
       else {
         None
       }
      }
      else {
       None
     }
    }
    else {
      None
    }
  }
```

Comment: Flip all the conditions and then or them together. If its tru return none. Otherwise do what you want to. One if. Yay done. Edit: ok doesnt get rid of the most internal, but i think theres a way you can do that part some other way.

Comment: Please ask this question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's so verbose is largely that you're formatting your code in a very inefficient way.  Look, here's the same code again:

```
def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
  val schemaValue = authHeader.split(' ')
  if (schemaValue.length == 2) {
    if (schemaValue(0).toLowerCase == "basic") {
      val decodedHeader = new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(schemaValue(1)))
      val decodedParts =  decodedHeader.split(':')
      if (decodedParts.length == 2) Some(decodedParts(0), decodedParts(1))
      else None
    }
    else None
  }
  else None
}
```

That's not so bad!  It's only half as long as the original.  Now, you called something `decodedHeader`, but you didn't actually use the value in more than one place.  You could just collapse that into one line if you don't need the name to tell the next person what is going on here.  (Maybe you do.  Being more succinct isn't always better if what you take out lets the reader understand what you're doing.)

```
def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
  val schemaValue = authHeader.split(' ')
  if (schemaValue.length == 2) {
    if (schemaValue(0).toLowerCase == "basic") {
      val decodedParts = new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(schemaValue(1))).split(':')
      if (decodedParts.length == 2) Some(decodedParts(0), decodedParts(1))
      else None
    }
    else None
  }
  else None
}
```

Finally, `return` is not idiomatic Scala in general, but they do wonders for making your code compact and readable when used in this kind of situation:

```
def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
  val schemaValue = authHeader.split(' ')
  if (schemaValue.length != 2) return None
  if (schemaValue(0).toLowerCase != "basic") return None
  val decodedParts = new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(schemaValue(1))).split(':')
  if (decodedParts.length == 2) Some(decodedParts(0), decodedParts(1))
  else None
}
```

You're now down to 8 lines (still quite readable IMO) from 25, and it's mostly formatting.  The logic is identical, and the language constructs (except for `return`) are identical.

The idiomatic way is, fortunately, nearly as compact in this case.  You'd use pattern matching instead, which helps condense your failure cases:

```
def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] =
  authHeader.split(' ') match {
    case Array(key, value) if key.toLowerCase == "basic" =>
      new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(value)).split(':') match {
        case Array(a, b) => Some((a,b))
        case _ => None
      }
    case _ => None
  }
```

This clocks in at 9 lines instead of 8 (even less if we pull the match statement onto the first function line, but it's already kind of long; note that we now have a function that is equal to an expression, so we don't need to wrap it in an extra `{}`), but it's mostly extra braces, and the good vs. bad cases are especially clear.

You can use `collect` to be even shorter, as you needn't specify what the failure case is (it is implicit in using an `Option`):

```
def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = Option(authHeader.split(' ')).
  collect{ case Array(key, value) if key.toLowerCase == "basic" => new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(value)).split(':') }.
  collect { case Array(a, b) => (a,b) }
```

We're now down to three lines, albeit pretty hairy ones.  I wouldn't recommend actually writing it this way.  Space out the `collect`s a bit so you can see what's going on.  Like so:

```
def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] =
  Option(authHeader.split(' ')).
    collect{ case Array(key, value) if key.toLowerCase == "basic" =>
      new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(value)).split(':')
    }.
    collect { case Array(a, b) => (a,b) }
```

Still not bad at 6 lines.  Whether this is the way you want to code depends on how comfortable your team is with collects.  It definitely expresses the logic (conditional transformation and testing) in a very compact way.

Comment: Why not `"(?i)basic (.*)".r` and an extractor for the decoder? `java.util.Base64` in contemporary Java.

Comment: @som-snytt - I played around with regex-based matching, but regexes are really another language (a limited, weakly-typed language), and it wasn't shorter than my really short collect version, so I didn't bother fleshing it out.  Also, I didn't use `java.util.Base64` only because the OP didn't. I should have mentioned that it's out of date, though.

Comment: As an exercise: `val r = "(?i)basic (.*)".r; object X { def unapply(s: String) = Option(Base64.getDecoder.decode(s).span(_ != ':')) collect { case (x,y) => (new String(x), new String(y drop 1)) } }` then `text match { case r(X((x,y))) => s"$x/$y" }`.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern matching can clean up a lot of the tests in the example.

```
  def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = {

    authHeader.split(' ') match {
      case Array("basic", buffer) =>
        new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(buffer)).split(':') match {
          case Array(dp1, dp2) => Some(dp1, dp1)
          case _ => None
        }
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

Comment: You lost the `toLowerCase`, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in `Option` and then use `map` and `filter` methods.

```
Option(authHeader.split(' '))
  .filter(parts => parts.length == 2 && parts(0).toLowerCase == "basic")
  .map(parts => new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(parts(1)))
  .map(_.split(':'))
  .filter(_.length == 2)
  .map(parts => (parts(0), parts(1)))
```

And if you are not a big fan of such one-liners, you can split it up to multiple expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the Option->filter->map pattern.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think to filter. This is what I had in mind thanks

Comment: No need for the final 'Some' though (I'd edit this but "edits need to be at least 6 characters"... even though they clearly don't...)

Comment: You can clean this up even more by replacing `filter` and `map` by `collect`. I also think pattern matching like in Wayne Tanners answers looks nicer than using `parts(0)`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens What's an example with collect? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: `collect` is a combination of `filter` and `map`. The last two lines could for example be `.collect { case Array(a, b) => (a, b) }`

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matching :

```
  def decodeAuthHeader(authHeader: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
    val schemaValue = authHeader.split(' ')
    schemaValue match {
      case arr if (arr.length == 2) && (arr(0).toLowerCase == "basic") =>
        val decodedHeader = new String(new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(schemaValue(1)))
        val decodedParts =  decodedHeader.split(':')
          decodedParts match {
          case t if (t.length == 2) => Some(decodedParts(0), decodedParts(1))
          case _ => None
        }
      case _ => None 
    }
  }
}
```